# Replace two queries with with one equivalent query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Can these two queries (that works fine) be replaced with one?

```
INSERT INTO temptable 
(
    `id`,`aggr`
)
select a.id, b.aggr
from main a
inner join  (
  select uk, group_concat(cascina_uk SEPARATOR '|') as aggr
  from main 
  group by  uk 
) b on a.uk = b.uk;

update main, temptable set main.aggr = temptable.aggr where main.id=temptable.id;
```

I don't need to create a temporary table. All I need is to update the main.aggr column.

Comment: No you cant replace a INSERT and UPDATE query with one equivalent query...

Comment: The first query looks like such a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL's multi-table update syntax:

```
update main, (
    select a.id, b.aggr
    from main a
    join (
        select uk, group_concat(cascina_uk SEPARATOR '|') as aggr
        from main 
        group by uk 
    ) b on a.uk = b.uk
) temptable
set main.aggr = temptable.aggr
where main.id = temptable.id
```

Note that I have only *rearranged* the parts of your query into a working query; I suspect there are optimisations that can be made to the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

From your query I understand that you are updating multiple `id` rows with same value of `aggr`. Then this one should work:

```
update main
set aggr = group_concat(cascina_uk SEPARATOR '|')
group by uk
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update main c
set 
  c.aggr = (select b.aggr 
               from 
                   main a,
                   (select uk, group_concat(cascina_uk SEPARATOR '|') as aggr from main group by uk ) b
               where 
                 a.uk = b.uk
                 and c.id = a.id)
```